# tensorflow TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'dict'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I have a problem. I try to execute this code but I got an error.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Visualizations will be shown in the notebook.
%matplotlib inline
import glob
import cv2
import numpy as np

def plot_figures(figures, nrows, ncols, labels=None):
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=ncols, nrows=nrows, figsize=(12, 14))
    axs = axs.ravel()
    for index, title in zip(range(len(figures)), figures):
        axs[index].imshow(figures[title], plt.gray())
        if(labels != None):
           axs[index].set_title(labels[index])
        else:
            axs[index].set_title(title)

        axs[index].set_axis_off()

    plt.tight_layout()

### Visualize your network's feature maps here.
### Feel free to use as many code cells as needed.

# image_input: the test image being fed into the network to produce the feature maps
# tf_activation: should be a tf variable name used during your training procedure that represents the calculated state of a specific weight layer
# activation_min/max: can be used to view the activation contrast in more detail, by default matplot sets min and max to the actual min and max values of the output
# plt_num: used to plot out multiple different weight feature map sets on the same block, just extend the plt number for each new feature map entry

def outputFeatureMap(image_input, tf_activation, activation_min=-1, activation_max=-1 ,plt_num=1):
    # Here make sure to preprocess your image_input in a way your network expects
    # with size, normalization, ect if needed
    # image_input =
    # Note: x should be the same name as your network's tensorflow data placeholder variable
    # If you get an error tf_activation is not defined it maybe having trouble accessing the variable from inside a function
    activation = tf_activation.eval(session=sess,feed_dict={x : image_input})
    featuremaps = activation.shape[3]
    plt.figure(plt_num, figsize=(15,15))
    for featuremap in range(featuremaps):
        plt.subplot(6,8, featuremap+1) # sets the number of feature maps to show on each row and column
        plt.title('FeatureMap ' + str(featuremap)) # displays the feature map number
        if activation_min != -1 & activation_max != -1:
            plt.imshow(activation[0,:,:, featuremap], interpolation="nearest", vmin =activation_min, vmax=activation_max, cmap="gray")
        elif activation_max != -1:
            plt.imshow(activation[0,:,:, featuremap], interpolation="nearest", vmax=activation_max, cmap="gray")
        elif activation_min !=-1:
            plt.imshow(activation[0,:,:, featuremap], interpolation="nearest", vmin=activation_min, cmap="gray")
        else:
            plt.imshow(activation[0,:,:, featuremap], interpolation="nearest", cmap="gray")       

my_images = sorted(glob.glob('./traffic_images/*.jpg'))
my_labels = np.array([1, 28, 17, 10, 33])
name_values = np.genfromtxt('signnames.csv', skip_header=1, dtype=[('myint','i8'), ('mysring','S55')], delimiter=',')

figures = {}
labels = {}
my_signs = []
index = 0
for my_image in my_images:
    img = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread(my_image), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    my_signs.append(img)
    figures[index] = img
    labels[index] = name_values[my_labels[index]][1].decode('ascii')
    index += 1

plot_figures(figures, 5, 1, labels)


### Run the predictions here and use the model to output the prediction for each image.
### Make sure to pre-process the images with the same pre-processing pipeline used earlier.
### Feel free to use as many code cells as needed.

my_signs = np.array(my_signs)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    saver.restore(sess, "./lenet")
    my_accuracy = evaluate(my_signs, my_labels)
    print("My Data Set Accuracy = {:.3f}".format(my_accuracy))

    ### Calculate the accuracy for these 5 new images. 
### For example, if the model predicted 1 out of 5 signs correctly, it's 20% accurate on these new images.
my_single_item_array = []
my_single_item_label_array = []

i = 0

for i in range(5):
    my_single_item_array.append(my_signs[i])
    my_single_item_label_array.append(my_labels[i])

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        saver.restore(sess, "./lenet")
        my_accuracy = evaluate(my_single_item_array, my_single_item_label_array)
        print('Image {}'.format(i+1))
        print("Image Accuracy = {:.3f}".format(my_accuracy))
        print()

k_size = 5
softmax_logits = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
top_k = tf.nn.top_k(softmax_logits, k=k_size)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    saver.restore(sess, "./lenet")
    my_softmax_logits = sess.run(softmax_logits, feed_dict={x: my_signs})
    my_top_k = sess.run(top_k, feed_dict={x: my_signs})
    for i in range(5):
        figures = {}
        labels = {}       
        figures[0] = my_signs[i]
        labels[0] = "Original"       
        for j in range(k_size):
            labels[j+1] = 'Guess {} : ({:.0f}%)'.format(j+1, 100*my_top_k[0][i][j])
            figures[j+1] = X_valid[np.argwhere(y_valid == my_top_k[1][i][j])[0]].squeeze()
        plot_figures(figures, 1, 6, labels) 
        ymax = figures[0].max()
        ymin = figures[0].min()
        outputFeatureMap(image_input=figures, tf_activation=softmax_logits, activation_min=ymin, activation_max=ymax , plt_num=k_size)
```

But I got this error message

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-58bf65741b75> in <module>()
    122         ymax = figures[0].max()
    123         ymin = figures[0].min()
--> 124         outputFeatureMap(image_input=figures, tf_activation=softmax_logits, activation_min=ymin, activation_max=ymax , plt_num=k_size)
    125 
    126 

<ipython-input-22-58bf65741b75> in outputFeatureMap(image_input, tf_activation, activation_min, activation_max, plt_num)
     38     # Note: x should be the same name as your network's tensorflow data placeholder variable
     39     # If you get an error tf_activation is not defined it maybe having trouble accessing the variable from inside a function
---> 40     activation = tf_activation.eval(session=sess,feed_dict={x : image_input})
     41     featuremaps = activation.shape[3]
     42     plt.figure(plt_num, figsize=(15,15))

/home/carnd/anaconda3/envs/carnd-term1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in eval(self, feed_dict, session)
    573 
    574     """
--> 575     return _eval_using_default_session(self, feed_dict, self.graph, session)
    576 
    577 

/home/carnd/anaconda3/envs/carnd-term1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in _eval_using_default_session(tensors, feed_dict, graph, session)
   3631                        "the tensor's graph is different from the session's "
   3632                        "graph.")
-> 3633   return session.run(tensors, feed_dict)
   3634 
   3635 

/home/carnd/anaconda3/envs/carnd-term1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    764     try:
    765       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 766                          run_metadata_ptr)
    767       if run_metadata:
    768         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/home/carnd/anaconda3/envs/carnd-term1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    935                 ' to a larger type (e.g. int64).')
    936 
--> 937           np_val = np.asarray(subfeed_val, dtype=subfeed_dtype)
    938 
    939           if not subfeed_t.get_shape().is_compatible_with(np_val.shape):

/home/carnd/anaconda3/envs/carnd-term1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    480 
    481     """
--> 482     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    483 
    484 def asanyarray(a, dtype=None, order=None):

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'dict'
```

I am not sure if the problem is the `tf_activation=softmax_logits` or if it is something else.  Anyone have any idea???

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I guess it is a problem with the input of the nn